# REST Business Logic and error handling

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I am trying to make a REST application where I try to hide to hide Business Logic from request and responses. 
I have to examples which I don't know how to handle.

First example: I have a shopping cart and product *x* can't be ordered with product *y*. The client however decided to order them both. How can I give a proper error message or guide the client that this isn't allowed. Because giving an error saying "*x* and *y* are not allowed together" seems like exposing Business Logic to me.

The structure is in place because of different services that we have. The products can be re-used, but the order intake is different. For example we can offer an order intake for vehicles which need different configuration when ordering cloths. In both cases you will have product, which have name and price and therefore can be re-used. That's is why vehicles and cloths can't be ordered together and shouldn't. To make this more user friendly there will be a service which presents available options for the specific order intake. But there should be a part which validates it and gives proper error on this.

Second example: A client has one pending order and can't create a new order when the pending order is completed. This seems/feels stateful to me and should probably avoided. How should this be handled?

**UPDATE** So resolving the issue for my first example could be to create an endpoint something like */products?type=vehicle* or */products/combinations?type=vehicle*. This is for displaying the allowed products/combinations and have an endpoint */order* to put the products in where the validation happens. These endpoints can stand on their own, but the context *may* come from somewhere else. Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer already pointed out, this is only marginally related to REST, it has I think more to do with the meaning of "exposing business logic" and "statelessness".

The first point of not wanting to expose business logic: It is only exposing business logic if some system really needs to *interpret* the specific error. If it is "only" supplying a localized message to the user, it is not exposing any logic to the systems in between. The frontend system does not need to know what is going on, it only needs to display the message from the backend system.

There are cases when the frontend system *needs to know*, to be able to guide the user. It is not fundamentally wrong to expose business logic, as long as it is not implicitly exposed, but explicitly part of the interface description.

On the second point about statelessness: REST defines that the *communication* needs to be stateless. That means any arbitrary request from client should be meaningful *without* the context of any previous messages (this includes previous logins, sessions, whatever). Each request stands on its own. This *does not* mean that specific resources can not keep a state of their own. A shopping cart on the backend does in fact has a state, this is OK.

Or said differently: Can the next request hit a different server and still be successful? And I mean without session replication, distributed cache or other magic. If yes, the communication is stateless. If you need "sticky" sessions or such things, then no, you are not stateless.

Comment: I think I understand. I updated the post with an example, can you tell me if you think this is true or false statement?

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand your description. What I meant was that you could just `POST` to `/mycart/`, and have it return `400 Bad Request`, if there was a semantic error, like 2 products can not be ordered together. The response can contain a proper description of the error, this would not be considered leaking business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think your questions are not entirely related to REST itself but I will try to answer them anyways. Maybe, you can give more details about what bothers you reading my answers.

I am not completely sure how the first question is related to REST because I feel it is about wording. The question to me would be: Why is it not allowed to order both of these products together? So, you cannot but them into the same shopping basket? This would not be really user-friendly, so the best idea would be to allow it. If you cannot change that both are not allowed at the same time, I would just "grey out" all the items that are not allowed together with product X if it is already in the shopping basket.

However, this is more of a user experience question. Maybe, you could go into detail here in what exact case a user could be insert both of the products at the same time, while it is not allowed.

Towards your second question: In most online shops you usually have a state that is either mapped to the account, a session or via cookies. If you truly want to have a stateless API here with REST, you could work with order IDs. These could be passed to each request. Of course, the order itself has a state. But the requests do not have one.

Notice: REST does not mean much. You basically have no state for each request and have all information in the URL that are necessary.

Maybe, this helps a bit already.

Comment: I have updated example 1. Your notice is helpful, I thought a service shouldn't expose business logic at all, so also no exception which describes the business logic error. From what I understand from you business logic is allowed in REST, but shouldn't be exposed in request and responses (like 'verbs')